# Using moment js with vuesjs fails

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, momentjs

I have installed moment js

```
npm install moment --save
```

Then in my root app.js

```
import moment from "moment";
```

Now in my components am trying

```
to: moment().day(2).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
```

But the above returns an error of

```
ReferenceError: moment is not defined"
```

WWhat could be wrong?

Comment: try importing in your component.

Comment: Try doing this `var moment = require('moment');`

Comment: Are you using `moment` in `template` like `{{ moment }}`, or it doesn't work in script?

Comment: @NickParsons it works ater importing in the component thanks.

Comment: @Traxo no am not using it that way.

Comment: @Catman155 thanks it now works.

Comment: @GEOFFREYMWANGI Sweet, I'll post it as a solution

Comment: sure ill mark it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
window.moment = require('moment');
```

it worked for me